# Validating a property if another property has a value on MVC 3/jQuery Validator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate

how can I use a Required Validation in a property Prop2 only if the Prop1 is true?

```
Ex:
public bool Prop1 { get; set; }

[Required] // I need this validation only if the Prop1 is true.
public string Prop2 { get; set; }
```

Any idea? I need on client and server side.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom validator do to this job.

Let me know if you need help to do it.

Comment: CustomValidator is for WebForms. He's asking about DataAnnotations in MVC.

Comment: What?! You don't know that you can write your custom validator and use it in MVC?! Watch this BradWilson presentation and learn! http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2011/02/advanced-aspnet-mvc-3-presentation.html

Comment: I'm saying a `CustomValidator` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx is different than the rules you add to the jQuery validation plugin.  By adding a validation provider, as in my answer, you're specifying the rules that are added.  These are parsed by jQuery on DOM ready.  Adding a single validation script isn't as flexible or reusable as allowing the DataAnnotations framework to generate these rules for you.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [**MVC FoolProof**](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) Validation framework

It has useful feature like

```
[RequiredIf]
[RequiredIfNot]
[RequiredIfTrue]
[RequiredIfFalse]
[RequiredIfEmpty]
[RequiredIfNotEmpty]
[RequiredIfRegExMatch]
[RequiredIfNotRegExMatch]

[Is]
[EqualTo]
[NotEqualTo]
[GreaterThan]
[LessThan]
[GreaterThanOrEqualTo]
[LessThanOrEqualTo]
```

Hope this would help you!

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to this.  First, you have to write a required attribute that's only required if the other property meets your criteria.

You'd have to do something like:

```
public class RequiredComparerAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public OtherProperty { get; set; }
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // TODO: use reflection to validate other property as PropertyInfo 
        // or validate it's value after it is decided to be valid

        foreach (ValidationAttribute va in property
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true)
            .OfType<ValidationAttribute>())
        {
            if (!va.IsValid(value))
            {
                return false; // not required
            }
        }
        return  true; // required
    }
}
```

Then, in Application_Start in the Global.asax, you'll have to register the validator, which you can just reuse the RequiredAttribute's validator:

```
        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
            .RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredComparerAttribute),
              typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
```

If you want to add your own validator, you'll have to write a custom validator.  Phil Haack has an example on his blog: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx

Edit:  Take a look at CompareAttribute in .NET Reflector for a sense of how to get the value of the OtherProperty. CompareAttribute also implements `IClientValidatable` to provide those validation rules needed on the client side.

I *don't* think CompareAttribute will work for you because you have to validate that a value is required based on content of another property, not compare the equality of two properties.

Edit2: **What does the Validation provider do?**

It adds rules to the form and provides messages for those rules.  You can see exactly how the `RequiredAttributeAdapter` does this by downloading the MVC 3 source.  To understand what it does on the client side, you can open the MVC 3 page in Google Chrome, hit CTRL+SHIFT+J to bring up a developer tools window and enter:

```
$('form:first').data().unobtrusiveValidation.options
```

The rules object inside options specifies how to validate each item and the message object specifies the error message that will be displayed for each validation error.

Edit3: **Full example**

Since answering this question, I've written a blog post with a full example of creating a custom attribute on the client (unobtrusive validation) and server.  The blog post is [here](http://www.ipreferjim.com/2011/08/dataannotations-mvc3-unobtrusive-validations/).  This example is for a 'contains' attribute, but it should be pretty easy to modify to become a required comparison.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that a custom validator is the best way. :)

Comment: @Cesar: inheriting from CustomValidationAttribute is probably the way to go so you don't have to do the reflection piece, but this post tells you exactly how to implement a server-side and client-side "custom validator".  If you mean a validation rule on the client side, here is a good explanation of those: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html

Comment: I wrote a blog post about how to create a custom DataAnnotations attribute for validation on both the client and the server.  [Read it here](http://www.ipreferjim.com/2011/08/dataannotations-mvc3-unobtrusive-validations/) and [source code here](https://github.com/jimschubert/ContainsAttributeExample)