# ASP.NET MVC data annotations attribute Range set from another property value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Hi I have following in my Asp.net MVc Model

TestModel.cs

```
public class TestModel
{      
public double OpeningAmount { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
[Display(Name = "amount")]
[Range(0 , double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The value must be greater than 0")]
public string amount { get; set; }

}
```

Now from my controller "OpeningAmount " is assign .

Finaly when I submit form I want to check that "amount" must be greater than "OpeningAmonut" . so want to set Range dynamically like

```
[Range(minimum = OpeningAmount , double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The value must be greater than 0")]
```

I do not want to use only Jquery or javascript because it will check only client side so possible I can set Range attribute minimum dynamically than it would be great for.

Comment: Data written in attributes are "constant" unless you write your own Custom Metadata Provider, where you can "adjust" these values.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382129/validating-a-property-if-another-property-has-a-value-on-mvc-3-jquery-validator/14293808#14293808

Comment: @Murali I have gone through this link but I don't think it could be useful to me?

Comment: @Dilip0165, Ok. I am removing it.. Thank you :)

Comment: @Murali I don't mean it . keep as it is . May be it could be helpful to someone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in attribute which can work with dependence between properties.

So if you want to work with attributes, you'll have to write a custom one.

Se [here](http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/asp-net-mvc-lessthan-and-greaterthan-validation-attributes/) for an example of what you need.

You can also take a look at [dataannotationsextensions.org](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/)

Another solution would be to work with a validation library, like (the very nice) [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) .

Comment: I will try it and let you know

Comment: I prefer your first link in which customvalidation is provided . Thanks for your support

Comment: Link to dataannotationextensions.org is dead. Do you know where moved or if they still exist?

Answer (score 10):

Recently there's been an amazing nuget that does just that: dynamic annotations and it's called [ExpressiveAnnotations](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations)

It allows you to do things that weren't possible before such as

```
[AssertThat("ReturnDate >= Today()")]
public DateTime? ReturnDate { get; set; }
```

or even

```
public bool GoAbroad { get; set; }
[RequiredIf("GoAbroad == true")]
public string PassportNumber { get; set; }
```

Comment: can you please tell me when to use `AssertThat` and when to use `RequiredIf` using ExpressiveAnnotations library?

Comment: @Thomas Use `AssertThat` when you want to write *business logic validation* on the property you're decorating

`RequiredIf` is a different thing. Use it when you have a property that sometimes is Required to have data (not left empty with no value) while sometimes else it can be empty. The logic of when it's required or not is what you write inside the `RequiredIf`.

Comment: can you please post a sample which guide me when to use AssertThat and when to use RequiredIf using ExpressiveAnnotations library. thanks