# client side Conditional validation RequiredIf attribute

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net MVC 4 view with two radio buttons. On page load, a section of the view is hidden using css. on view itself, when user selects one radio button, once section is hidden and other is displayed and when other radio button is clicked, other section is shown. I want to perform conditional validation so based on checkboxes checked. I have created RequriredIf attribute but it works on server side only. code is:

```
 public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private String PropertyName { get; set; }
        private String ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }

        public RequiredIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue, String errormessage)
        {
            this.PropertyName = propertyName;
            this.DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
            this.ErrorMessage = errormessage;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
        {
            Object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
            Type type = instance.GetType();
            Object proprtyvalue = type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null);
            if (proprtyvalue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString() && value == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

and here is how I a using this attribute:

```
 [RequiredIf("LocationType", LocationTypeEnum.BuildingOffice, "Please enter building number")]
        public string BuildingNumberName
        {
            get { return _BuildingNumberName; }
            set { _BuildingNumberName = value; }
        }

         [RequiredIf("LocationType", LocationTypeEnum.BuildingOffice, "Please enter floor number")]
        private string _Floor = string.Empty;

        public string Floor
        {
            get { return _Floor; }
            set { _Floor = value; }
        }

        private string _ApartmentOfficeNumber = string.Empty;

         [RequiredIf("LocationType", LocationTypeEnum.BuildingOffice, "Please enter appartment/office number")]
        public string ApartmentOfficeNumber
        {
            get { return _ApartmentOfficeNumber; }
            set { _ApartmentOfficeNumber = value; }
        }
```

and

```
private string _HouseNumber = string.Empty;

        [RequiredIf("LocationType", LocationTypeEnum.VillaHouse, "Please enter house number")]
        public string HouseNumber
        {
            get { return _HouseNumber; }
            set { _HouseNumber = value; }
        }
```

This has few drawback:

1) it does post back so user has to wait for postback and fix errors.
2) after postback, the default section is hidden(using css).

I want to make it using client side. What i need to do?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14293808/1559213 may be useful

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to add to your web.config file in order to enable client side validation.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>  
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: will it work for custom validation attribute as well ?